# Can reducer take multiple inputs from different mappers?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Can reducer take multiple inputs ?  The key is same for both mappers but value types are different. First is a MapReduce program that outputs (text, floatwritable) where floatwritable is the value type and text is key. Second is a mapper which outputs (text, SongStats) where SongStats is a custom data type implementing Writable. I want a reducer to take output of both earlier map reduce and the second mapper while running calculations. I think the output of first MapReduce program may be too big to hold in distributed cache. Any pointers would help. I am writing programs in Java.

Comment: please provide code samples while asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a reducer can only take in a specific input as defined in the method definition:

```
public void reduce(Key key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                  Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Your best bet is to write a new MapReduce job that uses `MultipleInputs` to convert the output of the previous MapReduce job (that had text, floatwritable) and the output of your other Mapper (that had text, SongStats) to a similar type (e.g. text, text or whatever can best suit your needs) and pass that to your reducer.

Sources:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html

Comment: That helped.  Thanks